# Can someone help me fixing this cannot find symbol error

Tags: java

I just started to learn programming with a book I got recently and it teaches me to write plugins for minecraft with java.The first task is to copie the following code it´s supposed to say Hallo Welt when I enter the minecraft world

```
import org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPlugin;

public class HalloWeltPlugin extends JavaPlugin { 
    public void onEnable() {
        this.getLogger().info("Hallo Welt!");
    }
 
    public void onDisable() {         
    }
}
```

But when i try to compile the code it shows following error:

```
HalloWeltPlugin.java:1: error: cannot find symbol
import org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPlugin;
                             ^
  symbol:   class JavaPlugin
  location: package org.bukkit.plugin.java
HalloWeltPlugin.java:3: error: cannot find symbol
public class HalloWeltPlugin extends JavaPlugin {
                                     ^
  symbol: class JavaPlugin
HalloWeltPlugin.java:5: error: cannot find symbol
        this.getLogger().info("Hallo Welt!");
            ^
  symbol: method getLogger()
3 errors
```

As i said i have no idea of programming yet and i would be happy if someone could tell me what the mistake is.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/25706216/12299000

Answer (score -1):

The Problem seems to be that the Class `JavaPlugin` can't be resolved hence it is a `symbol which can not be found`. Did you include the package `org.bukkit.plugin.java` into your project via maven/gradle or directly?

When you starting out with programming, I'd suggest you to start with the basics instead of jumping right into coding plugins for Minecraft.

A beginners guide to Java like [this](https://www.javacoffeebreak.com/java101/java101.html) would suite you better.